# Mandar valor desde actionResult a input

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Estoy intentando mandar un valor desde mi controlador a un input.
Lo intenté con el siguiente código y no funciona, ¿alguna sugerencia?

Lo estoy mandando a llamar desde un onclick.

Este es mi código:

```
public ActionResult Suma()
{

    decimal suma;
    suma = (decimal)Session["Suma"];

    return View(suma);
}
```

---

```
function Sumar() {

    $("#sub").empty();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("Suma","prueba")',
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (suma) {
            $('#sub').val(suma);

        },
    });
```

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. Lee **[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con la descripción de los errores que tengas.

Comment: Veo que estás iniciando en ASP.net MVC, te recomiendo ver este workshop que desarrollé tiempo atrás, espero te sea de utilidad: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yo creo que debería ser:

```
    public JsonResult Suma() {
        decimal suma;
        suma = (decimal)Session["Suma"];

        return Json(suma);
 }
```